# Partial update of the OLD site in the browser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

The user (client) has requested AddressForm.php, which contains a html form. From there, the user makes a http server request to Confirmation.php, and depending on the posted form values, the server should send the new screen (based on Confirmation.php), or it should partially update the old screen (based on AddressForm.php if Confirmation.php returns an error), by substituting the html tag `<DIV name="errormessage">no errors</DIV> into <DIV name="errormessage">error 123</DIV>`

How to implement a partial update of the `<DIV>` of the old site without having to recalculate for the values of the old site again?

Comment: A little abstract but basically you re-echo the old site and prefill the values.

Comment: @Forbs Can I achieve this without re-echoing the old site? something like going back to the old site with the old data but with the error message in the div  this time?

Answer (score 0):

In short, as an example, in the Confirmation.php file, I do the following using a session;

```
session_start(); // use sessions

$err = array();
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

//you may have an empty first name, last name or email (or message)
if(empty($email)) {
   $err[] = 'Please enter an email address';
}
if(empty($message)) {
   $err[] = 'Please enter a message to send';
}
```

If there is an error in the form, in this case an empty message, the following would be true;

```
if(count($err)) {
  $_SESSION['msg']['reg-err'] = implode('<br />',$err);
  header("Location: AddressForm.php");
  exit;
}
else {
  $_SESSION['msg']['reg-success']= "Thank you for submitting your message";
  header("Location: AddressForm.php");
  exit;
}
```

---

Then, in your AddressForm.php file, wherever you would like the error message to appear you can simply put:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_SESSION['msg']['reg-err'])) {
    echo '<div class="err">'.$_SESSION['msg']['reg-err'].'</div>';
    unset($_SESSION['msg']['reg-err']);
 }
 if(isset($_SESSION['msg']['reg-success'])) {
    echo '<div class="success">'.$_SESSION['msg']['reg-success'].'</div>';
    unset($_SESSION['msg']['reg-success']);
 }
?>
```